# why doesn't 'save image as' call action method in ie 11 and Firefox?

Tags: image, internet-explorer, firefox, model-view-controller, captcha

My cshtml code:

```
<img id="imgCapImage" alt="Captcha" src="@Url.Action("RefreshCaptcha", "Account")" />
```

My action code:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public FileContentResult RefreshCaptcha(string id)
{
    FileContentResult img = null;
        try
        {
            string rndCode = "";
            byte[] fileContentResult = VerificationTextGenerator(ref rndCode);
            Session["RandomCode"] = rndCode;
            img = new FileContentResult(fileContentResult, "image/gif");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {}
        return img;
}
```

Everything is ok on chrome. When I clicked on 'save image as', it calls action method, and I refresh the captcha because of security issues to prevent captcha resolution by 3rd party libs. But if I do same in ie and firefox, it doesn't call action method and downloads image directly?
Is it possible? I googled it, but nothing found.

Comment: I'd like to ask that which library you use. I could not run your code due to VerificationTextGenerator() is not identified. Besides, I'm confused about what 'save image as' means. Is it the browser right click options or your customized button?

Comment: @JeniferJiang Thanks for your reply. Yes I mean browser right click. VerificationTextGenerator does produce an image simply in memory and return byte array.